# How to display preview Image and title from external links like how facebook does

Tags: reactjs, hyperlink, next.js, preview

I'm using react and next I really have no idea how to create a preview like this:
[image]

I've tried searching but cannot get the right terms.

Comment: you can use this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@dhaiwat10/react-link-preview

Answer (score -1):

This concept is not just preview it is also SEO:
First, you should get your data through getServerSideProps:
second data that come from getServerSideProps you should add data to Head data like this:

```
   // pages/single/[...slug].js

  const SinglePage = ({post, fullUrl }) => {
  return (
  <Head>
    <title>{post[0]?.title}</title>
    <meta name="description" content={`${post[0]?.excerpt}`} />
    <meta property="og:title" content={post[0]?.title} />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:url" content={`${fullUrl}`} />
    <meta
      property="og:image"
      content={`${
        post[0]?.featured_image?.formats?.thumbnail?.url ||
        post[0]?.featured_image?.url
      }`}
    />
  </Head>
    <div>
      .....content
     </div>
    )
   export default SinglePage;
   export async function getServerSideProps(ctx) {
     const { origin } = absoluteUrl(ctx.req);
     const slug = ctx?.query?.slug[0] || "";
     const post = await getSinglePost(slug);
     return{
        props: {
           post : post,
           fullUrl :  origin + "/single/" + slug
        }
      }
   }
```

now deploy your project to vercel then send the link of single page to telegram of someone then you will see the preview.

Comment: I know meta tags and preview is SEO stuff, what I need is when adding the link it should show a preview. My website it the one where I copy and paste the site link with meta tags preview. My goal is to show it

Comment: when you write your code as I wrote website shows the image automatically.

Comment: What I want to copy is the preview feature.

Comment: preview future can only be done the way i have answered get data and set data to Head tag i have worked a project like this i will send the link then copy the link in a social app you will see the preview.

Comment: I know my question is how to implement showing the preview after pasting on WYSWIG form like facebook. Yours is adding meta tags.